# Active Directory roles not displaying

Tags: active-directory-module

A while ago I created some documentation on configuring roles in Sitecore for my team. We're using Sitecore 9.0 with the `Active Directory` module. I set my documentation aside six or so months ago because we didn't have a real world use case for it yet.

I came back to that documentation today, but now when I search for roles (which I know exist in AD) I never get any search results. Nothing. This is really strange since I have screenshots of it working in my old documentation! We have not upgraded Sitecore or anything since then. Not much has changed other than migrating another large website into Sitecore.

I Googled my problem and there was a guy who said increasing the cache sizes in the `ldap.config` fixed his problem, so I increased mine from 5MB to 100MB but it didn't help. I still have the same issue. Any ideas what may be causing this problem? Our `LDAP` configuration is still working because I can search for individual user accounts just fine, just not AD roles. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was pretty simple. At some point someone on our team had disabled the role manager portion in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore Experience Platform 9.1.0 or later does not support the Active Directory module. Below is the link for your reference.

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Active_Directory.aspx

Comment: My mistake, we're using 9.0, not 9.1, with Active Directory Module 1.4.